# What does 'GA' mean for sourcecode?

Tags: release-management, application-lifecycle, software-lifecycle

What does GA stand for?

Like: 1.0.0.GA - Bean Validation (JSR-303)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means **General availability** or **general acceptance**.

To quote wikipedia:

**General availability** or **general acceptance** (GA) is the point where all necessary commercialization activities have been completed and the software has been made available to the general market either via the web or physical media.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle

Answer (score 1):

GA stands for GENERAL AVAILABILITY in a software release.